# Graph of Fresnal function vs its derivative.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

I'm trying to understand a graph in my textbook. I'm introduced to the Fresnel function which is this:

$$\int_0^x \sin(\pi \cdot t^2 / 2) dt$$

vs this function:

$$\sin(\pi \cdot t^2 / 2)$$

These are supposed to be the graphs:

[image]

At $x = 1$, how is S less than f if S is supposed to be the integral? Shouldn't it definitely be bigger than f at $x = 1$?

Comment: Why do you think $\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ must necessarily be larger than $f(1)$?  Consider also $f(x) = x^2$.  Or just $f(x) = x$.

Comment: f(1) = 1 and so shouldn't S(1) be at least 1?

Comment: No.  There's no general property that says that.

Comment: Recall that $\displaystyle\int_0^1 f(x) \, dx$ is the area between the graph of $f(x)$ and the $x$-axis for $0 \le x \le 1$.  Does it really look like there is more than one unit of area in that region for $f$ in Figure 7?

Comment: I guess I'm incorrectly thinking that since f(1) = 1, then an area including f(1) should be > 1. Is this not right? Why am I wrong?

Comment: Try taking calculus out of the picture.  $f(1) = 1$ is the length of one side of the boundary of the region.  From a plane geometry perspective, there is no general relationship between the area of a region and the length of one of the region's sides, so there's no way to say which one has a larger numeric value. An exception (or maybe **the** exception) is a square, of course, where the area is the length of a side squared. But even then.. if the square has a side length smaller than 1, then the area of the square will have an even smaller numeric value, e.g., 1/2 squared = 1/4, and 1/4 < 1/2

Comment: Note also that comparing $f(x)$ and $S(x)$ doesn't make much sense, since $f(1)$ is a length of a boundary (e.g., meters), and $S(x) = \int_0^x f(t) \, dt$ is an area (e.g., meters squared).  $S(1)$ may be "bigger" in the sense that $f(1)$ fits "inside" $S(1)$ geometrically, but $f(x)$ and $S(x)$ measure completely different things:  length and area.